# Convert object to HTML Input in JQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an object as below. Is there any way to convert this to HTML inputs separately in jQuery or JavaScript?

Object:

```
{
  "OrderID": 110,
  "TKOrderStatus": 61,
  "Description": "Order Updated",
  "IsActive": true,
  "IsDeleted": false,
  "IPAddress": "::1",
  "CreatedAt": "\/Date(1568972577698)\/",
  "ID": 0
}
```

Expected HTML output:

```
<input type="text" name="OrderID" value="110" />
<input type="text" name="TKOrderStatus" value="61" />
<input type="text" name="Description" value="Order Updated" />
<input type="text" name="IsActive" value="true" />
<input type="text" name="IsDeleted" value="false" />
<input type="text" name="IPAddress" value="::1" />
<input type="text" name="CreatedAt" value="\/Date(1568972577698)\/" />
<input type="text" name="ID" value="0" />
```

Comment: *your attempt* - missing

Comment: Actually I don't know approach. I try to find a solution way

Comment: Just FYI, you've got an object there, not JSON. I've amended the question as such.

Comment: No it's JSON. Assume it has been converted from string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a main loop on array of objects and a inner loop that loops through all the keys:

**jQuery**

```js
let orderArr = [{
    "OrderID": 110,
    "TKOrderStatus": 61,
    "Description": "Order Updated",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "IPAddress": "::1",
    "CreatedAt": "\/Date(1568972577698)\/",
    "ID": 0
  },
  {
    "OrderID": 120,
    "TKOrderStatus": 62,
    "Description": "Order Updated new",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "IPAddress": "::2",
    "CreatedAt": "\/Date(1568972577000)\/",
    "ID": 0
  }
];
orderArr.forEach(function(order) {
  Object.keys(order).forEach((key) => {
    $('#container').append('<input type="text" name=' + key + ' value=' + order[key] + '>')
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
let orderArr = [{
    "OrderID": 110,
    "TKOrderStatus": 61,
    "Description": "Order Updated",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "IPAddress": "::1",
    "CreatedAt": "\/Date(1568972577698)\/",
    "ID": 0
  },
  {
    "OrderID": 120,
    "TKOrderStatus": 62,
    "Description": "Order Updated new",
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "IPAddress": "::2",
    "CreatedAt": "\/Date(1568972577000)\/",
    "ID": 0
  }
];
orderArr.forEach(function(order) {
  Object.keys(order).forEach((key) => {
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += ('<input type="text" name=' + key + ' value=' + order[key] + '>')
  });

})
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `append` to append the values and `Object.keys` to get the keys and corresponding values from the object

```js
var a={
  "OrderID": 110,
  "TKOrderStatus": 61,
  "Description": "Order Updated",
  "IsActive": true,
  "IsDeleted": false,
  "IPAddress": "::1",
  "CreatedAt": "\/Date(1568972577698)\/",
  "ID": 0
};
Object.keys(a).forEach(function(e){
$('#q').append('<input type="text" name='+e+' value='+a[e]+'>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="q"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the end, we are one family, so this is the code for you.

```js
const obj = {
  "OrderID": 110,
  "TKOrderStatus": 61,
  "Description": "Order Updated",
  "IsActive": true,
  "IsDeleted": false,
  "IPAddress": "::1",
  "CreatedAt": "\/Date(1568972577698)\/",
  "ID": 0
};

const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
for(const key in obj) {
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('name', key);
  input.value = obj[key];
  wrapper.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```